# How to recover/install windows from .zip file?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, recovery

I have an **i-Life ZED Air X** and I tried to install Windows from a bootable USB, which installed correctly; however, brightness, sound, power, and many others are not working correctly due to a driver issue and there is no driver available online.

Previously, I downloaded from the official website firmware section *(not available currently)* `ZED AIR X - IL.1303.4120GB.BCAEGR,BCAEGO.zip`, which contains three folders:

```
sources
images
efi
```

How can I recover windows 10 from this zip file, as YouTube shows to use WinPE, but no WinPE 64bit is available online?

Comment: If Windows was installed by downloading the [Media Creation Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) from Microsoft, a reinstall isn't needed to install drivers _(if it wasn't from Microsoft or the laptop's OEM, a reinstall would be recommended to ensure the integrity of the `install.<esd||wim>`)_. To install drivers, everything but CPU-related drivers can be installed via Windows Update, whereas CPU-related drivers and OEM-specific software would need to be downloaded from the OEM's support site

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ If `ZED AIR X - IL.1303.4120GB.BCAEGR,BCAEGO.zip` is from the OEM, please post a screenshot of what's included within the `images` directory, as this may contain an OEM recovery `.wim` or `.swm` files, and if so, you can restore the laptop to it's factory state via that, which should have been captured with all OEM drivers/software installed.

Comment: "no WinPE 64bit is available online?" - Yes; It absolutely is.  It's included with every 64-bit Windows 10 ISO. WinPE is the Windows installation environment.

Comment: @JW0914 yes the images contain,
Images\backup(folder)
Images\Winre.wim
Images\Unattend.xml
Images\ReleaseAfter.cmd
Images\Install3.swm
Images\Install2.swm
Images\Install.swm

Comment: @MusfiqurPavel You can use the `.swm` files to restore Windows a few different ways: by booting the WinPE `Winre.wim`, which should auto-load the OEM recovery UI; or by booting any WinPE WIM and using [`Dism /Apply-Image`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image) to apply then to the OS partition _(OEM recovery `.swm`'s should contain the full OS filesystem - `.swm` are split-WIM files split at certain size, often 4GB)_,

Comment: @MusfiqurPavel _(Cont'd...)_  The easiest way to to do this will be to create a bootable USB and extract the `.zip` to the root of the USB; however without knowing the complete directory tree of it, it may be easier to create a bootable USB via Microsoft's Media Creation Tool. If doing the latter, rename the Media Creation Tool's USB's `sources\boot.wim` to `boot-orig.wim`, extract the `.zip` to the root of the USB's partition, copy `images\Winre.wim` to `sources\boot.wim`, then boot the USB.

Comment: @MusfiqurPavel Thinking about it further, you may need to fiddle around with where the files within the `images` directory are placed _(`Winre.wim` still needs to be copied to `sources` and renamed `boot.wim`)_, and it would help to give a more definitive answer if you could post the contents of `images\ReleaseAfter.cmd` and `images\unattend.xml` within separate code boxes _in your question_, as the OEM could have configured WInPE _(WinRE is WinPE, containing WinPE OCs specific to recovery)_ to either look in the root of the boot media for those files, or within the `images` directory